# Pass by value in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

When trying to call grid.arrange to put multiple plots on a same ggplot2 graph, I first build a list of the plots I want. Then I build the corresponding argument list to call grid.arrange, as was explained [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681145/how-can-i-arrange-an-arbitrary-number-of-ggplots-using-grid-arrange). This is my code (my dataframe is called manip):

```
args.list <- NULL;
plot.list <- NULL;
for (m in names(manip[2:10])) {
  plot.list <- c(plot.list, list(qplot(manip$side, y=manip[,m],ylab=m))
}
args.list <- c(plot.list, 1, 9)
names(args.list) <- c(names(manip)[2:10], list("nrow","ncol"))
do.call(grid.arrange, args.list)
```

This works, except that the 9 graphs are exactly the same! After checking, it turns out that the data is always the one corresponding to `m=10`. So my guess was that the value of `m` is not assigned in the loop, but evaluated later. However, the label `ylab=m` **is** assigned correctly and is different for all the graphs.

So I don't really get what the difference is and how the interpreter chooses when to evaluate m for the plots. Can someone explain?

Comment: Is there a reason why you build the plots separately rather than using facets?

Comment: @Andrie: I guess that I could, but I would need to restructure my data frame

Comment: That probably won't be difficult.  In my answer I show both approaches.  Reshaping your data.frame should only be two extra statements.  One to load `reshape2` and the second to `melt` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will first answer your question and then show an alternative using a facet plot.

**Edited**

The following, much simplified, code seems to work:

```
library(gridExtra)
manip <- mtcars
plot.list <- lapply(2:11, 
                    function(x)qplot(manip$mpg, y=manip[, x], 
                    ylab=names(manip)[x]))
do.call(grid.arrange, c(plot.list, nrow=10))
```

It produces this ugly plot:
[image]

---

Without knowing your objectives, it is dangerous to try and give advice, I know.  Nonetheless, have you considered using facets for your plot instead?

The following code is much simpler, executes quiker and produces a graph that is easier to interpret:

```
library(reshape2)
manip <- mtcars
mmanip <- melt(manip, id.vars="mpg")
str(mmanip)
ggplot(mmanip, aes(x=mpg, y=value)) + 
    geom_point(stat="identity") + 
    facet_grid(.~variable, scales="free")
```

[image]

Comment: Note that probably the first one does not work. All panels should have the same values.

Comment: @kohske: exactly, that's my point, it has the same problem as my solution; Andrie: I will try to use faceting, but would still be interested in knowing how to fix the problem that I brought up

Comment: @kohske Well spotted.  I think my edited answer works.  The approach is quite different, so the OP needs to verify this is what he had in mind.

Comment: @Andrie looks nice solution. And see my answer for the probably typical workaround.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior is due to the lazy evaluation of R.

Here is a minimal(?) example:

```
d <- 1:3

args.list <- NULL;
plot.list <- NULL;
for (m in 1:3) {
 plot.list <- c(plot.list, list(qplot(d[m], d[m], ylab=letters[m])))
}

args.list <- c(plot.list, nrow=1, ncol=3)
do.call(grid.arrange, args.list)
```

in this case, `d[m]` is evaluated at the call of `do.call`. so `m` is 3 for all panel.

here is a workaround:

```
d <- 1:3

args.list <- NULL;
plot.list <- NULL;
for (m in 1:3) {
  plot.list <- c(plot.list,
    list(qplot(d, d, data=data.frame(d=d[m]), ylab=letters[m])))
}

args.list <- c(plot.list, nrow=1, ncol=3)
do.call(grid.arrange, args.list)
```

in this case, `d[m]` is evaluated at the call of `qplot`, and the `d[m]` is stored in the output object of qplot.

so, the simple solution is to pass data to `qplot()` or `ggplot()`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would be better to melt then data and use faceting?

```
library(ggplot2)
manip <- data.frame(car = row.names(mtcars), mtcars)
manip.m  <- melt(manip)
qplot(car, value, data = manip.m) + facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y")
```

It need some polishing in the xlab

```
last_plot() + opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

HTH