# Increasing space between plots in rmarkdown

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

I am trying to plot two figures in one line and I want to increase the space between them. I searched this forum and a few other websites but none of the options I found seems to be working. Changing the `mai`, `mar` and `oma` values moved everything around but the space remains the same. How can I keep the figures as they are now (size wise) but increasing the gap between them?

Here is my code:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, fig.width=6, fig.height=6}
g.erd <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 150, type="gnm")
par(mfrow = c(1, 2),  mai = c(1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
plot(g.erd, layout=layout.circle, vertex.label=NA)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, fig.width=3, fig.height=3.5}
hist(degree(g.erd), xlab="Degree", ylab="Frequency", main="")
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))  
```
````

and here is how my plot looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Fc7.png

Comment: what is your output format?  html, pdf, word?  One solution would be to add some CSS if you're using html output

Comment: grid table might help you here, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529926/arrange-ggplots-together-in-custom-ratios-and-spacing

Answer (score 7):

A 'hackish' solution in ggplot2 would be to put extra line spaces before the beginning of your second graph's title with \n like so:

ggtitle("\n\nPlot Title")

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding markdown breaks between each chunk. `<br>`, like this:

````
```{r, echo=F}
plot(cars)
```

<br><br><br>

```{r, echo=F}
plot(cars)
```
````

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

You can stack multiple `<br>` to achieve the desired gap you want.

Answer (score 0):

This approach *kind of* works. It depends on why you want the different sizes, but you may be able to fiddle with the layout `width` and `height` parameters, or the `par(mar=c()` to get the spacing and size you want. You could also create a layout that have 3 plotting areas, and leave one blank, as a way to try to force the smaller histogram into the desired location (`layout.show(layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3),ncol=2)))`).

````
```{r echo=FALSE, fig.width=6, fig.height=6}
library(igraph)
g.erd <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 150, type="gnm")

layout(matrix(c(1,2), ncol=2), width=c(1,1))
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(g.erd, layout=layout.circle, vertex.label=NA)

par(mar=c(10,5,9,1))
hist(degree(g.erd), xlab="Degree", ylab="Frequency", main="")
```
````

Hope this helps. Good luck.

edit: I've changed the plotting code to approximate equal graph size, but it's just sort of a guess, and other folks might be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: So I actually want to have both figures to be of the same size and further apart then they are. But I can't figure out hoy to control for a plot placement in markdown. When I tried to put them with just one size (i.e., not splitting into two chunks) the graph was miniature compared to the histogram.

Comment: Would it be possible to eyeball it by altering `mar` of each plot. igraph plots tend tend to have weird margins?